# set up windows on a workspace

Tags: unity, command-line, 14.04, compiz, workspaces

I'd like to set up a command that can restore all of my windows after a reboot.

I typically have a set of windows per workspace (multiple monitors) for a particular task.  After I reboot (which is more frequent now because apparently SSDs aren't supposed to hibernate) I set each of these workspaces up.

Ideally I could run something like:

```
./restoreWindows 1 work
./restoreWindows 2 play
```

The first command would "restore windows" on workspace #1 for the "work" profile, which I'd define ahead of time as:

- terminal on screen 1 occupying left half of screen started in directory `workProject`
- terminal on screen 1 occupying right half of screen started in directory `workProject` running command `grunt`
- chrome/chromium browser on screen 2 [with tabs]

terminal and chrome/chromium are pretty much all I need restored.

I'd also settle for something that restored windows of a particular profile on the current desktop:

```
./restoreDesktop work #restores on active workspace
```

Comment: You have failed to mention which x-window manager system you are using....that might help others provide a specific answer to your question.